# Почему не редактируется объект?

Tags: javascript, dom

Я хочу отредактировать контакт, но после  подтверждения, получаю ошибку:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'dataset' of null

Помогите пожалуйста исправить ошибку

```js
// create table    
load() {
        let tBody = document.querySelector('tbody');

        tBody.innerHTML = '';

        for (let i = 0; i < this.items.length; i++) {
            let tr = document.createElement('tr');
            tr.classList.add('data');
            tr.dataset.id = i;
            tr.innerHTML = `
                                <th scope="row" class="checkBox"><input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" bid ="${i}"></th>
                                <td>${this.items[i].fname}</td>
                                <td>${this.items[i].phone}</td>
                                <td>${this.items[i].email}</td>
                                <td ><i class="far fa-edit" data-id="edit"></i> | <i class="far fa-trash-alt"  data-id="rubbish"></i></td>
                            `;
            tBody.append(tr);
        }

        this.list = [];
        this.checkedList = [];
        this.multiSel();
    }

// edit contact 

    edit(i) {

        const d = document;

            const fname = d.querySelector('#Edname').value;
            const phone =  d.querySelector('#Edphone').value;
            const email =  d.querySelector('#Edemail').value;
            this.items[i] = new BookItem(fname,phone,email);

        this.save();
        this.load();

    }

btnS.addEventListener('click', (e) => {

        app.UserBook.edit(+e.target.closest('tr').dataset.id);
},false);
```

Comment: Возможно `load()` вызывается после `addEventListener`.
Ошибка указывает на эту строку? app.UserBook.edit(+e.target.closest('tr').dataset.id)

Comment: верстку приложите, у вас `tr` не находится и возвращается `null` при `closest('tr')`

Comment: @Nyan да,  на эту строку, я  пытаюсь tr  сделать  индексом  контакта, но как я понимаю,  она не успевает инициализироваться